# Text appears unclear kind of pixelated

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a CustomScrollView widget with SliverLists and a SliverGrid on one screen of my app, when I first load the main screen the text appears fine, but when I scroll to the bottom of the screen and then back to the top, the two buttons MAKE A SALE and ADD PRODUCT the text appears unclear and pixelated.

Not sure if anyone has experienced this or knows the reason why, but I would sure appreciate some help with this.

This issue is happening only on my iPhone 14 Pro, Samsung Galaxy S21. It is NOT happening on my iPhone 7

[image]

In this picture you can see that those two buttons the text is less clear than the rest of the screen's text.

the screen's main build function:

```
return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf8f9f8),
          body: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                    Container(
                      width: size.width,
                      color: color_bluepurple,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(height: 40),
                          Container(
                            width: inputWidth,
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                    .start,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                    .spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      ProfileAvatar(),
                                      IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            widget.GetAccountData();
                                          },
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.refresh)
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Badge(
                                    badgeContent: Text(notificationLen.toString()),
                                    child: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.white),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                                width: inputWidth,
                                height: 201,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: AssetImage(
                                        'assets/images/dashboard_bg.png',
                                      ),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(15)),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                        .start,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                        .start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Hello, " +
                                          accountData["userprofile"]["company"],
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey)
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(height: 75),
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            child: Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                                  .start,
                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                                  .start,
                                              children: [
                                                Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text("₦",
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 28,
                                                          fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                        )),
                                                    Text(balance,
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .white,
                                                            fontSize: 35)
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                Text(
                                                    "Your Wallet Balance",
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors
                                                            .grey)
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            width: inputWidth * 0.20,
                                            child: IconButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                HideBalance();
                                              },
                                              icon: Icon(
                                                  Icons.remove_red_eye,
                                                  color: balanceIconColor),),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],),
                                )
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                  .center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                  .center,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: inputWidth / 2 - 15,
                                  child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) => AddSale(products, productsStrings, widget.GetAccountData)
                                          )
                                      );
                                    },
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.edit,
                                        color: Colors.black),
                                    label: Text("MAKE A SALE",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                          color: Colors.black,

                                        )),
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        primary: Colors.white,
                                        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius
                                                .circular(10))
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 25),
                                Container(
                                  width: inputWidth / 2 - 15,
                                  child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) => AddProduct(suppliers, suppliersStrings, widget.GetAccountData)
                                          )
                                      );
                                    },
                                    icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.add, color: Colors.black),
                                    label: Text("ADD PRODUCT",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            color: Colors.black
                                        )),
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        primary: Colors.white,
                                        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius
                                                .circular(10))
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 25),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    overviewSelected = true;
                                    transactionsSelected = false;
                                    expensesSelected = false;
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Text("OVERVIEW",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        color: Colors.white
                                    )),
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    overviewSelected = false;
                                    transactionsSelected = true;
                                    expensesSelected = false;
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Text("TRANSACTIONS",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        color: Colors.white
                                    )),
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    overviewSelected = false;
                                    transactionsSelected = false;
                                    expensesSelected = true;
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Text("EXPENSES",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        color: Colors.white
                                    )),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          TabUnderline(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    // SizedBox(height: 15),
                  ]),
                ),
                Content(inputWidth, todaysProfits, salesToday, productCount, totalSalesCounter, totalSales, productsWithSales),
                TopSellingProductsHeader(),
                TopSellingProducts(),
                SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                  SizedBox(height: 50),
                ]))
              ]));
```

The Content() you see in this code returns a SliverList, so does TopSellingProductsHeader.
TopSellingProducts() returns a SliverGrid.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you tried adding some extra padding around the Text? I feel like I remember having a similar issue before and that fixed it (however, that was on web and this is on android)

Comment: Appreciate the comment, unfortunately that did not solve the issue.

Comment: I think [this is the issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58159) I was having before, which appears to be only web. Can you try switching to the default font family and see if you still have the issue then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something to do with the size of the MAKE A SALE and ADD PRODUCT buttons, I reduced them by 10 pixels width and it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your CustomScrollView with the Expanded widget and see if the issue still persists.

Comment: ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.